# Hashicorp-Vault: Possible to store besides key and value also "notes"?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

We are switching from KeePass to HashiCorps vault.
In our KeePass, we always had for each entry, 3 columns.
The username (key), password (value) and notes, to add additional infos/notes.

In vault, theres the KV engine, in which we can add only a Key with its Value.

Is there a other engine, addon or feature that could help us out, having a Key/Value/Notes table?

We are using vault over the website:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The KV secret engine can store arbitrary documents. You need to [keep each entry under 1MiB](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/internals/limits#storage-entry-size), it should not be a problem.

You just need to specify all of them on the command line, like this (shown here with quotes and multiple lines):

```
vault kv put kv/legacy-database username=scott password=tiger \
   note="That old Oracle database that runs under Mike's desk"
```

Using the Vault UI, you would do something like this for every single secret you have in KeePass

[image: Entering a multi-valued secret in Hashicorp Vault kv store]

If you are using a library, most (all?) of them accept a mapping type (like a Python `dict`) that can hold any number of arbitrary values.

Getting the value back is as straightforward. You can cherry pick a single field:

```
$ vault kv get --field note kv/legacy-database
That old Oracle database that runs under Mike's desk
```

Or get the whole thing back (show here in full JSON):

```
$ vault kv get --format json kv/legacy-database
{
  "request_id": "c5de914d-526a-a478-0a35-8a1a2a7b3012",
  "lease_id": "",
  "lease_duration": 0,
  "renewable": false,
  "data": {
    "data": {
      "note": "That old Oracle database that runs under Mike's desk",
      "password": "tiger",
      "username": "scott"
    },
    "metadata": {
      "created_time": "2023-08-10T14:14:22.699717829Z",
      "custom_metadata": null,
      "deletion_time": "",
      "destroyed": false,
      "version": 3
    }
  },
  "warnings": null
}
```

Comment: So we are using vault only over the vault website. Is it also possible to do it there?

Comment: I added a screenshot to the main question.
Is it possible to add a third column into the UI? Beside of Key and Value text fields.

Comment: Short answer is "No". But I think you are not using Vault the way it was intended. Each "secret" should be its own entry. You will get a list of secrets by their name, then drill down in each of them. It is a security feature. If you must look at a any part of a secret on your screen and someone looks over your shoulder, they can only steal that one.